# Android display list of records from a database(sqlite)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to display a list of items which has a name "Bernadette" in my android application.
My code looks like this:

```
public List<WebsiteRecords> getAllWebsite() {
    List<WebsiteRecords> websites = new ArrayList<WebsiteRecords>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + "WHERE user=?", new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        WebsiteRecords website = cursorToWebsite(cursor);
        websites.add(website);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return websites;
}

private WebsiteRecords cursorToWebsite(Cursor cursor) {
    WebsiteRecords website = new WebsiteRecords();
    website.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    website.setUser(cursor.getString(1));
    website.setSitename(cursor.getString(2));
    website.setUsername(cursor.getString(3));
    website.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));
    return website;
}
```

but when I run it, it says that the application has stopped working and my logcat says:

```
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bernadette.remembermypassword/com.bernadette.remembermypassword.PasswordActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM websitesWHERE user=?
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM websitesWHERE user=?
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at com.bernadette.remembermypassword.DataSource.getAllWebsite(DataSource.java:62)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at com.bernadette.remembermypassword.PasswordActivity.show_list_layout(PasswordActivity.java:172)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at com.bernadette.remembermypassword.PasswordActivity.onCreate(PasswordActivity.java:42)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-28 09:07:26.922: E/AndroidRuntime(835):  ... 11 more
```

can you help me about this? I have a database called users which have _id, user, site, username, password columns. and when I login in my application, i want to display lists of items which have a the same "user" names. What should I do with it?

I also want to know if I am typing the right set of codes, because as I keep running it, still it display all the records from the db and not only showing up the list from the username I showed in Toast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is on

```
" WHERE user=?", new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER});
```

change the value of "?"  directly.

use

```
 database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL);
```

instead of

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + "WHERE user=?", new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER});
```

Comment: so i have to do it like " WHERE user= user" ? how do I code it?

Comment: so I have to remove the new String[] thingy?

Comment: just use "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL instead "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + "WHERE user=? if you want to get all.

Comment: but i want to select the items only from a certain user. I toast the username in my Main Activity java file

Comment: but aren't passing the specific user. 
try this "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + "WHERE user="+user;

Comment: do i need to put the user inside my public List<WebsiteRecords> getAllWebsite()?

Comment: Yes. List<WebsiteRecords> getAllWebsite(long userId)

Comment: I tried making it String user, but I get another error in my other java file in getAllWebsite section saying "The method getAllWebsite(String) in the type DataSource is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + "WHERE user=?", new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER});
```

You need another space before the `WHERE`, change the line to

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL + " WHERE user=?", new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USER});
```

Comment: will it display the lists of the current user logged in?

Comment: it doesn't display my list from the current user logged in